# Azure Cloud Service (Classic) Staging slot fails to start, and gives no errors

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have inherited a project running on Azure's Cloud Service (Classic).  I have a build of the app that, when pushing to the staging slot, will not launch the staging slot. I can find no errors anywhere in the table logs or activity log stating a failure of any kind.  The activity log actually shows `Write DeploymentSlots Accepted`.  The staging slot sits with blank information.

[image]

There is also a "test" environment set up for this app, and the same build pushed to that starts with no issue. As far as I can tell the two environments are identical.

Comment: Do you deploy it from Visual Studio, or you create the package and upload it? Any error message in Visual Studio during the deploy?